# The veracity of doing hget and hset on the same value in a redis hash (inside a pipeline)

Tags: redis

In redis, I have a hash where I want to first get and then set a value. I reckon I can use pipelining to speed up the whole operation via downsizing the round trips, like so:

```
my_pipeline = redis.Redis(connection_pool=POOL).pipeline()
my_pipeline.hget("my_hash","my_time")
my_pipeline.hset("my_hash","my_time",latest_time)
result = my_pipeline.execute()
old_value_of_my_time = result[0]
```

Essentially I've tried to retrieve the original value of `my_time` for later use, and then set a new value.

**So the question is:** is doing `hget` and `hset` on the same value in the same pipeline correct? I understand from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634826/redis-pipelined-order-of-execution?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) (and general knowledge of pipelines) that the order of commands is preserved in pipelines. So ostensibly, my approach should be correct.

However I might be missing something, so can an expert vet this approach?

*Note: I've used python syntax in the example code. Moreover, if I wasn't using a hash, I'd simply use `getset` for this operation. But note that I must use a hash in this case - for reasons outside the scope of this question.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do `HGET` and `HSET` in the pipeline. However, it behaves slightly different from `GETSET`. `GETSET` is an atomic operation, but the combination of `HGET` and `HSET` in a pipeline is **NOT** atomic.

Redis guarantees that it runs your `HGET` command before your `HSET` command. However, Redis **DOES NOT** run these two commands atomically. So when it runs your `HSET` command, the `HASH` might already be modified by another client. In this case, you do not get the old value, but some older value.

In order to achieve something similar to `GETSET`, you have run `HGET` and `HSET` in a transaction, or wrap these two commands in a `Lua` script.

Comment: Does redis support atomic transactions natively?

Comment: Of course. You can achieve that with [transaction related commands](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) or [Lua scripting](https://redis.io/commands/eval).

Comment: out of scope for the question but I thought I'd put it forth. Do you speak python? I ask because in the docs (here: http://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the python wrapper, it seems `pipeline` is implemented with `transaction=True` by default? I just want to confirm.